# Why a DNS server on an ATA?

Tags: voip, dns

I was portscanning this home network from the outside and found three open ports: telnet(!), http and domain. I quickly realized that those ports were belonging to an Eltek R7121-L1 ATA that is connected before the router. Http and telnet are obviously for administration, but what is the DNS-server used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I looked up the specs of this device they say it supports DNS SRV under RFC:2782. You can find the specs [here](http://www.eltektec.com/en/products/voip/voip-ata/eltek-r7121-l1-detail)

You can find additional information about DNS SRV at [RFC2782](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2782.txt).
Here is some good information using [DNS SRV with a SIP implementation](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/DNS+SRV):